# run instrumentation test using Espresso: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

Tags: android, instrumentation, android-espresso

I am testing the system app Contacts on platform Kitkat using the google-espresso. My test project located in #android-dir#/cts/tests/tests/contactTest.

Here is the .mk:

```shell
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# don't include this package in any target
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
# and when built explicitly put it in the data partition
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_DATA_APPS)

LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android.test.runner

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += librarycontacts

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := shared

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := contactsTest

LOCAL_INSTRUMENTATION_FOR := Contacts

include $(BUILD_CTS_PACKAGE)

##################################################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += librarycontacts:libs/espresso-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bundled.jar

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

Here is the Manifest.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.contacts.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.android.contacts" />

    <application>
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the commands:

```mk
> $ mmm cts/tests/tests/contactsTest/
> $ adb install -r out/target/product/generic/data/app/contactsTest.apk
> $ adb shell am instrument -w -r com.android.contacts.test/com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner
```

then I got this error:

```mk
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
```

It's all OK when I compiling and running it with eclipse. and it just fails here, I've tried both `espresso-dependencies` and `espresso-standalone` following the [guideline](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso#Espresso_Setup_Instructions), all do not work.

This problem really messed me up.
I'm new to here,any reply appreciated. thanks.

Comment: rebuilding the target project Contacts fixed this issue but I dont know why.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue with Espresso 2 and eventually found the dependency issue was with the support library. I added the following `configurations` to the top level of `build.gradle` to resolve the issue.

```
configurations {
    androidTestCompile.exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    androidTestCompile.exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
    // more dependencies

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
}
```

Comment: This solved it for me but I'm curious to know how you identified that the support library was the culprit. You are awesome!

Comment: The issue was harder than most to debug. I think one of the support classes (related to Drawer, IIRC) was prominent in the stack trace, and that made me go in this direction.

Comment: What I did was saw the dependencies from https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/pom.xml and found that espresso also uses appcompat-v7 and I was also using it. So adding `androidTestCompile.exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'` to configurations, and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

I tried to exclude Guava and it did not work. It's not a "nice" solution but it works:

```
adb shell setprop dalvik.vm.dexopt-flags v=n,o=v
adb shell stop installd
adb shell start installd
```

Execute them on a terminal prior to run the tests.

Comment: Do you know how to revert those settings as well?

Comment: @Nilzor try this command out: `adb shell setprop dalvik.vm.dexopt-flags ''`.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I was working with Guava and Espresso also contains Guava.

If you use Gradle and Android Studio you can exclude packages from the dependency like this:

```
androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3') {
   exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an annoying error, but one that is relatively easy to fix. The reason you get it is because you have multiple versions of the same class in the same process, typically i na test project this is because you have a library in your test app that exists in your real application or you are compiling in your app to the test apk and when the test runs it blows up.

To fix this all you have to do is change anything that is in your test app and your app to be a provided dependency.

Comment: Maybe I should figure out what is the dependency exactly, But how? I mean that I am already using the `espresso-standalone` library which Google provided it to deal with the 'dependency'. Can you give me some advice? Eagerly looking forward to your reply.